# Creating a multiple column combobox in Java

Tags: java, combobox, multiple-columns

I need to create a ComboBox in Java that will have information in a column on the left and a Checkbox in a column on the right so that a user can select multiple items in the ComboBox. This needs to be a ComboBox because there could be 100 items in the list that may need to be checked but they cannot take up much space on the user interface.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't think a ComboBox is the correct UI element for this situation. How about a scrollable ListView?

Comment: try this : http://www.coderanch.com/t/340213/GUI/java/Multiple-Columns-JCombobox , dont know if it works or not ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `JList` inside a `JScrollPane` seems more appropriate for dealing with that many items.  It supports the standard CTRL-click to select multiple items.

A multi-selection combobox with 100 items sounds like a UI nightmare.